# Symfony datepicker picks currentdate on 2nd submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datepicker

I am using the symfony form to create a datepicker that will inform the use on the deliverydate of his order

```
->add('deliveryDate', 'date', array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy/MM/dd',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => ['class'=>'datepicker'],
                ));
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="col s6">
    {{form_label(form.deliveryDate)}}{{ form_widget(form.deliveryDate) }} <br>
  </div>
```

This gets saved in the order Entity using the following format: `2017-01-12 00:00:00`

however when I have submitted the form the 1st time and set it to example 12 January it will save the 12th of January. When I resubmit the form again, not changing the date in the datepicker the value will set itself to 30th of january. Even though the value in the field is displayed properly as 12th. I can't seem to figure out why it resets.

UPDATE:
From what I figured out it now is that in second submit with no changes it (and not null) it will always pick the currentdate as new date. Maybe this helps anyone trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: which plugin are you using for that datepicker?

Comment: This is what I based my code on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is probably being set as null because your controller is not properly persisting the submitted date. Try dumping the date after the request is handled to see what the format is.

```
var_dump($myForm->get('deliveryDate')->getData());
```